# Ruby and Moment.js passing time that does not generate error

Tags: ruby, vue.js, momentjs

I do this in my controller `(Time.now - 5.seconds).iso8601` and pass that to my front end which is built in Vue.

The time my controller returns is in this format:

```
2021-03-13T00:17:32.602Z
```

On the front end I am displaying the humanized form of the above date like this:

```
a few seconds ago
```

In my Vue front end, things look great BUT, I continue to get this error:

```
Could not build a valid `moment` object from input.
```

The vue code that displays this is:

```
{{ item.last_synced | moment("from") }}
```

What can I do to get rid of that error? Unfortunately I cannot ignore, as this is for an app, and the marketplace will reject me app if it has any warnings.

Comment: Can you give us the Vue code that tries to create a `moment` instance?

Comment: @Aetherus just updated the OP

Comment: What's the value of `item.last_synced`? The `| moment('from')` part looks like a filter to me. Did you make a filter out of the original `moment`?

Comment: `item.last_synced` is `2021-03-13T00:17:32.602Z` and then I'm just following these directions.. https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment#filtering-methods

Comment: Sorry for being late cuz I was playing with vue-moment. I guess you got the warning because `item` was an empty object before the data is fetched from your Rails app, and `| moment('from')` was trying to render `item.last_synced` immediately after the vue component is created, and at that time `item.last_synced` is `undefined`.

Comment: The solution is to either give the default `item` a default `last_synced`, or not to render it at all when it's not ready to be rendered (by using a `v-if`)

Comment: yep that was it.. it was trying to render before the data was available.. thanks for the idea!